# Reusing common step definitions between feature files in behave python

Tags: python-3.x, python-behave

i have some checks that needs to be included in multiple feature files i don't want to duplicate the step definitions across other step definitions.

eg:

```
@when(u'parquet files exist in "{container}" container in the data lake')                                           
def step_imp(context, container):
parquet_files_array = []
for parquet_file in context.list_of_files:
    parquet_files_array.append(parquet_file.name)
check_parquet_files_are_present_in_the_container_area_data_lake(parquet_files_array)**
```

i have to use this check in another step definition files too.

I have created a common_steps.py class and stuck all the common steps there i wonder how can reuse them with out duplicating across multiple features

Comment: Actually you can have multiple step definition files in `features/steps` directory. If you haven't done so - just move your `common_steps.py` file into steps directory. You should be able to use steps defined in this file across all of your features.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try importing them?

```
# in <step definitions>.py
import common_steps

@when(u'parquet files exist in "{container}" container in the data lake')                                           
def step_imp(*args, **kwargs):
    common_steps.step_imp(*args, **kwargs)



#in common_steps.py
def step_imp(context, container):
    # implementation
```

Answer (score 0):

When the common_steps.py is imported we don't have to define the step in the respective step definition file when we execute the feature file the step definition will be accessed from common_steps automatically